# WebRequest Credentials

Tags: c#

I am using console app to access WebApi.

I am creating WebRequest as follows:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

if (username == String.Empty)
{
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
}

else
{
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
}
```

I am opening command window using:

```
runas /savecred /user:test_user cmd
```

The problem is, if a username and password is supplied, the app is still connecting as "test_user" and ignores supplied username and password.

My question is: How can I make WebRequest to use the supplied username and password?

Comment: Have you used a step-through debugger to find out what it's doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the parameter *savecred* is saving the credentials. Try running this:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

and remove "test_user". Then run your program again without *savecred*.

Comment: Worked after removing the saved credentials. Thanks